# gcloud crashed (OSError): [Errno 28] No space left on device

Tags: google-cloud-platform

Every time I try to initiate datalab on google cloud I get the following error:

gcloud crashed (OSError): [Errno 28] No space left on device

This is the code I use on the command line (following the instructions on https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cpb100-datalab/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#1).

datalab create mydatalabvm --zone europe-west1-b.

Any help? I have nothing stored so I do not see how I cannot have any space left on device.

Comment: Did you try to change the zone?

Comment: Yes, this happens in any zone